# How to create a double bar contrast plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate a plot using `ggplot2` to show the performance between two soccer teams. I look for getting this plot:

[image]

I have the data `df` for that. This is the code I have been using:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=type,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  geom_text(aes(label=abs(value),hjust=1))+
  coord_flip()
```

Which produces next result:

[image]

The result is far away from first plot.

The issues I face are next:

1. The scale is too large for some type values, so is not possible to see each measure with independent scale. I think a `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()` would solve this but it did not worked.
2. The values for type must go in the middle, but I do not know how to move the axis to middle.
3. The labels for each bar should be on top of each bar but when I adjust `hjust` one of them goes to the right place but the other is placed wrong.
4. Finally, in `df` there is column named `logo` which stores the flags of two teams, how I can add the flags for each team one at top right side and the other at top left side.

Many thanks. This is the data `df`.

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(type = c("Shots on Goal", "Shots off Goal", "Total Shots", 
"Blocked Shots", "Shots insidebox", "Shots outsidebox", "Fouls", 
"Corner Kicks", "Offsides", "Ball Possession % ", "Yellow Cards", 
"Red Cards", "Goalkeeper Saves", "Total passes", "Passes accurate", 
"Passes %", "Shots on Goal", "Shots off Goal", "Total Shots", 
"Blocked Shots", "Shots insidebox", "Shots outsidebox", "Fouls", 
"Corner Kicks", "Offsides", "Ball Possession % ", "Yellow Cards", 
"Red Cards", "Goalkeeper Saves", "Total passes", "Passes accurate", 
"Passes %"), value = c(7, 2, 13, 4, 10, 3, 9, 8, 2, 78, 0, 0, 
1, 797, 716, 90, -3, -4, -8, -1, -6, -2, -14, 0, -2, -22, -2, 
0, -1, -215, -142, -66), name = c("England", "England", "England", 
"England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", 
"England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", 
"England", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", 
"Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", 
"Iran"), logo = c("https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/10.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png", 
"https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/22.png")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggimage)

df %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(tot = sum(abs(value)),
         prop = value/tot) %>%
  ggplot(aes(prop, type, color = name)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = -1, xmax = 1), color = "gray95", linewidth = 3) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = prop, xmax = 0), linewidth = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#8ded05", "#00aaff")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = type, x = 0), check_overlap = TRUE, nudge_y = 0.4,
            color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = ifelse(name == "England", 1.05, -1.05), 
                label = abs(value)), color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.1, 0)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(-0.5, 0.5), y = c(17, 17),
           label = c("Iran", "England"), size = 5) +
  geom_image(data = data.frame(x = c(1, -1), y = 17, 
                               image = unique(df$logo)),
             aes(x, y, image = image), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  guides(color = guide_none())
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. Bet me by "minutes". Fiddled around to add the logos. But otherwise 100% identical to my approach. :D

Comment: @stefan lol. Forgot to add the flags though...whoops.

Comment: Some small differences though. I sticked with geom_col, added the labels via geom_label to get the default padding and used geom_richtext for the logos.

Comment: @AllanCameron Amazing!

Comment: @stefan Despite this olution being amazing, I would like to see yours to make a choice!